# There doesn't seem to be a question about "The disk drive for tmp is not ready yet"

Tags: discussion

This is an error which I have seen many times, and yet while there are multiple questions about it ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499136/problem-after-installing-14-04-the-disk-drive-for-tmp-is-not-ready-yet-or-not-p) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392099/error-message-in-ubiquity-before-partitioning)), none of them are up voted. Is this because there is no answer, or I can't search and find the accepted one?

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be a bug.

[The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/1091792)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

- [Disk Drive / not ready yet or not available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34997/disk-drive-not-ready-yet-or-not-available)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /tmp could not be mounted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted)

In both cases the suggested fix is the same (to remount / rw), so it is probably just two different errors messages (one each for / and /tmp) representing the same underlying problem.

edit: Also [Disk drive boot problem: The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or is not present!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454037/disk-drive-boot-problem/462435#462435) which had answer:

> This is a bug in Ubuntu - [Ubuntu bug #1091792](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/1091792). It was fixed in
>   mountall-2.48 for Ubuntu 13.04. Unfortunately the latest version in
>   Ubuntu 12.04 is mountall-2.36.4, so it is not fixed (and, presumably,
>   never will be).